# How should I do to get the last record using LINQ?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

even if there is similar questions and answers about this but I couldn't get it to work.
I want to display the last record , I mean the last employees I have in my table and display him/her in dataGridview with
Firstname, Lastname and so on. When I reload this function in windows form then I get this error

> "index was out of range. must be nonnegative and less than the size of the collection"

Here is my code and not working. Thank you in advance

```
var employee = db.Employees.
               OrderByDescending(s =>s.EmployeeId).
                                  
               Select(b => new
               {
                  Id = b.EmployeeId,
                  FirstName = b.FirstName,
                  LastName = b.LastName,
                  Birthday = b.BOF  
                                    
                }).First();

                    if(employee != null)
                    {
                        dgvEmployee.DataSource = employee;
                        dgvEmployee.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                    }
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception? Debug that "service" data source. Make sure dgvEmployee has columns.  That title doesn't exactly match your problem.

Comment: I advise you to step through your code and find out, where excactly the error is thrown and use `FirstOrDefault()`. `First()` will throw an `InvlidOperationException`, if there are no elments in the sequence.

Comment: @JohnG , sorry I puted wrong text, I have just edited from service to employee , but stil the same error

Comment: Yuo've get last record, but you fail later. It is too obvious question, just debug. `dgvEmployee.Columns[0]` - probably your problem, grid have not refreshed rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change method from first to FirstORDefault.

```
var employee = db.Employees.
               OrderByDescending(s =>s.EmployeeId).                                  
               Select(b => new
               {
                  Id = b.EmployeeId,
                  FirstName = b.FirstName,
                  LastName = b.LastName,
                  Birthday = b.BOF  
                                    
                }).FirstORDefault();
```

Comment: thank you for you response, but this FirstOrDefault() givs me empty, no data reterning givs me empty GridView, but if I use Tolist() instead of FirstOrDefautl() then I get all emplyees

Answer (score 0):

```
var employee = db.Employees.
               OrderByDescending(s =>s.EmployeeId).                                  
               Select(b => new
               {
                  Id = b.EmployeeId,
                  FirstName = b.FirstName,
                  LastName = b.LastName,
                  Birthday = b.BOF  
                                    
                }).take(1);
or 
var employee = db.Employees.
               OrderByDescending(s =>s.EmployeeId).                                  
               Select(b => new
               {
                  Id = b.EmployeeId,
                  FirstName = b.FirstName,
                  LastName = b.LastName,
                  Birthday = b.BOF  
                                    
                }).FirstORDefault();

both are works
```

Comment: thank you for your response, the first one with .Take(1) givs me error that Dbset, DbQuery .. not supported , the other one givs me empty, no data reterning givs me empty GridView, but if I use Tolist() instead of FirstOrDefautl() then I get all emplyees

Answer (score 0):

1. `employee != null` Is useless if you use `First()` - read about [How does First work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netcore-3.1)
2. I assume, you get exception on this line `dgvEmployee.Columns[0].Visible = false;`. If you debug your code, you will notice that `dgvEmployee.Columns[0]` is empty

Answer (score 0):

build a data table and use this code.

> private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
> var db = new linqDataContext();
>
> ```
>         var employee = db.Employees.
>             OrderByDescending(s => s.EmployeeId).
>
>             Select(b => new
>             {
>                 Id = b.EmployeeId,
>                 FirstName = b.FirstName,
>                 LastName = b.LastName,
>                 Birthday = b.BOF
>
>             });
>
>         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
>         dt.Columns.Add("ID");
>         dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
>         dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
>         dt.Columns.Add("Birthday");
>         foreach (var item in employee)
>         {
>             var row = dt.NewRow();
>             row[("ID")] = item.Id;
>             row[("FirstName")] = item.FirstName;
>             row[("LastName")] = item.LastName;
>             row[("Birthday")] = item.Birthday;
>             dt.Rows.Add(row);
>         }
>
>         MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["ID"].ToString());
>     }
> ```

Comment: Hi Manoochehr Sheikhzadeh, welocome on SO! I suggest you, when answering, to explain a little what the code does, in order to allow OP to understand what was wrong with its original question/code! Keep posting awesome answers and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `where` clause followed by OrderByDescending and .Take() method should do it.

```
var tempFileName = db.Employees
                             .Where(x 
                                 => x.Id = b.EmployeeId,
                                    x.FirstName = b.FirstName,
                                    x.LastName = b.LastName,
                                    x.Birthday = b.BOF)
                             .OrderByDescending(x => x.EmployeeId)
                             .Take(1)
                             .Select(x => x.FirstName)
                             .ToList()
                             .FirstOrDefault();
```